# How to test a class contains @Lazy @autowired bean in spring JUnit

Tags: junit, annotations, mockito

I have a class in spring project which contains `@Autowire` bean with `@Lazy` annotation. 
At run time I am getting below errors while testing the class using junit.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy(value=true)}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please..what do you actually want . When the exception is coming while running test cases or while initializing the application?